# org.apache.cordova.media not respecting silent mode (Android)

Tags: android, cordova

I am creating an app which plays sound when correct answer is selected. Know the issue is I want that the audio should not be played when phone is in silent mode.
I tried to find the solution but didn't found any alternative for android device.
This issue is solved in iphone using this code:

```
 var snd = new Media(url); 
snd.play({ playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked : false });
```

but this didn't worked with android.
Solve it will be great help if we can detect the android device is in silent mode.
Please can any one help to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Originally, playAudioWhenScreenIsLocked was only available on IOS. You will need this pull request:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/pull/121
To make it working on Android.